# Como separar una cadena grande de tipo string por dos delimitadores

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, net

necesito separar una cadena de texto muy grande por renglones pero esta cadena tiene saltos de linea y lo que se requiere es obtener por ejemplo :
6.1 TEXTO
6.2
TEXTO y MAS TEXTO
6.3
TEXTO _________
MAS TEXTO
UNO MAS
6.4

lo que tengo hasta ahora es la separación de la cadena en dos partes primero obtengo toda la cadena como arriba , después separo nuevamente pero solo los saltos de linea "\n"

```
int posInicial = text.LastIndexOf("FAIL \n") + 1;
            int longitud = text.IndexOf(" REV. ") - posInicial;

          string  resultado = text.Substring(posInicial, longitud);
            // Split authors separated by a comma followed by space  
           textList = resultado.Split("AIL");

            //Si el array [0] contiene CHECKLIST inserta en otra parte.
            textCheckList = textList[0];

            if (textCheckList.Contains("CHECK LIST")) {

                actualizaDatobd = 1;

            }else
            {
                mandaDatoBD = textList[1];
                contadorDatoBd++;

                string []sentencia;
                for (int x = 1; x <= mandaDatoBD.Length; x++)
                {
                   //Se llena con cada salto de linea . 
                    sentencia = mandaDatoBD.Split("\n" );
                }
               

                //Se Empieza a mandar a BD Dato por bloque y ContadorDatoBD
                conexion.MandaBloques(contadorDatoBd, mandaDatoBD);

            }
```

me falta el como separa por "\n" y detectar que el siguiente carácter sea número decimal.
Mi código obtiene la separación por salto pero se necesita la otra validación por lo ya mencionado. Para tener la salida en :

salida 1 = 6.1 DATO
salidda 2 = 6.1.1
Mas datos del 2.
salida 3 = 6.1.2
otro dato.
.

Comment: Quieres separar la cadena cuando encuentre un numero decimal ?

Comment: Cadena == string, no es necesario decir que una cadena es de tipo string, al menos no en C# (o cualquier otro lenguaje que tenga el tipo cadena). Saludos

Comment: Ok tal vez por el contratiempo que tengo comente eso, pero bueno tendrás alguna respuesta más especifica con el problema ? .

Comment: @TheOligarch si es necesario, pero no del todo ya que dentro de la cadena encontramos decimales para las mediciones , entonces se separarán , es en especifico hay salto de linea ?, y comienza con decimales? , separa entonces : ejemplo : 6.1 UN DATO  6.2 DATO DOS SALTO DE LINEA DATO 6.3  ..salto .. mas datos .... Es en efecto tener por renglones cada punto correspondiente.